# find Minimum Window Substring

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Given a string S and a string T, find the minimum window in S which will contain all the characters in T in complexity O(n).

For example,

```
S = "ADOBECODEBANC"
T = "ABC"
```

Minimum window is "BANC".

Update,

I read one implementation from http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html, and the implementation seems wrong, which does not decrease count, and also does not move begin when find a matched window? Thanks.

```
// Returns false if no valid window is found. Else returns 
// true and updates minWindowBegin and minWindowEnd with the 
// starting and ending position of the minimum window.
bool minWindow(const char* S, const char *T, 
               int &minWindowBegin, int &minWindowEnd) {
  int sLen = strlen(S);
  int tLen = strlen(T);
  int needToFind[256] = {0};

  for (int i = 0; i < tLen; i++)
    needToFind[T[i]]++;

  int hasFound[256] = {0};
  int minWindowLen = INT_MAX;
  int count = 0;
  for (int begin = 0, end = 0; end < sLen; end++) {
    // skip characters not in T
    if (needToFind[S[end]] == 0) continue;
    hasFound[S[end]]++;
    if (hasFound[S[end]] <= needToFind[S[end]])
      count++;

    // if window constraint is satisfied
    if (count == tLen) {
      // advance begin index as far right as possible,
      // stop when advancing breaks window constraint.
      while (needToFind[S[begin]] == 0 ||
            hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]]) {
        if (hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]])
          hasFound[S[begin]]--;
        begin++;
      }

      // update minWindow if a minimum length is met
      int windowLen = end - begin + 1;
      if (windowLen < minWindowLen) {
        minWindowBegin = begin;
        minWindowEnd = end;
        minWindowLen = windowLen;
      } // end if
    } // end if
  } // end for

  return (count == tLen) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, have you tried anything?

Comment: @EdChum, no ideas how to implement by O(n). So far, I build a Hashtable to record whether any letter of T is hit, but no ideas how to track minimum coverage, so your advice and guidance is appreciated. :)

Comment: At the moment the question lacks effort and it's possibly more suitable for [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please check this: [Find the smallest window](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-window-in-a-string-containing-all-characters-of-another-string/).

Comment: @LinMa http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html would be worth linking.. do you just want someone to rewrite the code to python?

Comment: @liborm, read the implementation here (http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html), I think the if condition "if (hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]])" is useless and we can remove it, and unconditionally execute hasFound[S[begin]]--, how do you think?

Comment: @LinMa don't think so, the while condition is a disjunction (or), so the code inside the loop can execute even when hasFound[S[begin]] <= needToFind[S[begin]]

Comment: @liborm, I think hasFound[S[begin]] < needToFind[S[begin]] will not be executed since we have another restriction condition outside count == tLen? Please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: @liborm, updated my answer and find some issues in the implementation, appreciated if you could help to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I've coded a 'pythonic' implementation instead of trying to work with the C code. You can check my answer, and discuss it further if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method:

- Create a hash of `T` (because order of characters in `t` does not matter, we will use its hash)
- Now take two pointers (to iterate through `S`), both indexed at `0` to begin with. Let their names be `i,j`.
- Increment `j` at each step and calculate hash of `S` as you move forward. When this hash covers hash of `T` (of course you will need to compare the two hashes at each step), start to increment `i` (and decrement hash values in hash of `S`) until hash remains covered.
- When hash of `S` < hash of `T`, start again by incrementing `j`.
- At any point, the least window size of `i..j` that covers hash of `T` is your answer.

PS: take care of the corner cases, like end of string and all. I'll help if you need the code, but I'd recommend if you try it yourself first and then ask doubts.

Comment: how do you prove in your solution, you find the true minimum windows and not missing anything? :)

Comment: I am finding the window size that (firstly,) just covers the pattern `T` and then, decreasing that window until it no longer covers `T`. So, when I am decreasing the window size, it goes to minimum window size (until that value of `j`) that covers `T`.

Comment: smart and smart. I am also reading another implementation here (http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html), I think the if condition "if (hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]])" is useless and we can remove it, and unconditionally execute hasFound[S[begin]]--, how do you think?

Comment: @LinMa, It is important, as if `needToFind[S[begin]] == 0` and `hasFound[S[begin]] < needToFind[S[begin]]`, it is not required to decrement `hasFound[S[begin]]`, because, it is not in the pattern.

Comment: in while condition (one statement before), it is already checked the condition of "hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]]", not sure why in the next following statement, we need if condition to check again the same "hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]]"?

Comment: while statement has logical OR condition for which, if 1st condition is true, it won't check the second condition, which is rechecked in following `if`

Comment: so it is to avoid under the condition of needToFind[S[begin]] == 0, decrease hasFound[S[begin]]?

Comment: updated my answer and find some issues in the implementation, appreciated if you could help to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that String S and T only contains `A-Z` characters (26 characters)

- First, create an array `count`, which store the frequency of each characters in `T`.
- Process each character in S, maintaining a window `l, r`, which will be the current minimum window that contains all characters in T.
- We maintain an array `cur` to store the current frequency of characters in window. If the frequency of the character at the left end of the window is greater than needed frequency, we increase `l`

Sample Code:

```
    int[]count = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < T.length; i++)
        count[T[i] - 'A']++;

    int need = 0;//Number of unique characters in T
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if(count[i] > 0)
           need++;
    int l = 0, r = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int result ;
    int[]cur = new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < S.length; i++){
         cur[S[i] - 'A']++;
         r = i;
         if(cur[S[i] - 'A'] == count[S[i] - `A`]){
             count++;                 
         }
         //Update the start of the window,
         while(cur[S[l] - 'A'] > count[S[l] - 'A']){
               cur[S[l] - 'A']--;
               l++;
         } 
         if(count == need)
             result = min(result, r - l + 1);
    }
```

Each character in S will be processed at most two times, which give us O(n) complexity.

Comment: I'm not saying this with any bad intentions, but why do you post the exact same answer that is given before while you only change the words and way of explanation?

Comment: (And the answer before you was given more than 40 min before, not like you would have missed it).

Comment: @vish4071 I am not calculating any hash :) Hashing is correct (though there are a lot of corner cases, for example to match `aab`, so hash function should return same hash values for `acab` or `aaccb`), but you still need to compare everything to avoid collision.

Comment: @vish4071 so, I think it is fair to say that though the starting ideas is similar, but my solution is different than yours :)

Comment: Isn't your `count` same as my `hash`? Anyway, lets not continue this discussion. I'm sorry.

Comment: @vish4071 no, `count` is not similar to hash, np :)

Comment: @PhamTrung, what do you mean "frequency of the character at the left end of the window is greater than needed frequency", show an example? :)

Comment: @LinMa for example, if the current window is `aba`, and string t is `ab`, so, the frequency of character `a` is 2, while we only need 1, thus, we decrease the size of the window by one, which forms a new window `ba`. Another example, if we have a string `accab`, and string t is `ab`, so the window will look like this: `a` -> `ac` -> `acc` -> `a` - > `ab`

Comment: @PhamTrung, smart and smart. I am also reading another implementation here (http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html), I think the if condition "if (hasFound[S[begin]] > needToFind[S[begin]])" is useless and we can remove it, and unconditionally execute hasFound[S[begin]]--, how do you think?

Comment: @PhamTrung, updated my answer and find some issues in the implementation, appreciated if you could help to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
def minWindow(self, s, t):
    """
    :type s: str
    :type t: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    count = len(t)
    require = [0] * 128
    chSet = [False] * 128
    for i in range(count):
        require[ord(t[i])] += 1
        chSet[ord(t[i])] = True
    i = -1
    j = 0
    minLen = 999999999
    minIdx = 0
    while i < len(s) and j < len(s):
        if count > 0:
            i += 1
            if i == len(s):
                index = 0
            else:
                index = ord(s[i])
            require[index] -= 1
            if chSet[index] and require[index] >=0:
                count -= 1
        else:
            if minLen > i - j + 1:
                minLen = i - j + 1
                minIdx = j
            require[ord(s[j])] += 1
            if chSet[ord(s[j])] and require[ord(s[j])] > 0:
                count += 1
            j += 1
    if minLen == 999999999:
        return ""
    return s[minIdx:minIdx+minLen]
```

The method I used was to map the characters and how many are in the substring vs how many are needed. If all the values are non-negative, then you can remove characters from the start of the substring until you reach a negative, and if there's a negative, you add to the end of the substring until it is 0 again. You continue this until you've reached the end of S, and then remove characters until you have a negative count for one of the characters.

Going through the example, S="ADOBECODEBANC" and T="ABC". Starting out, the map has the values A=-1, B=-1, C=-1, and has a count of 3 negatives. Adding the first letter increases A to 0, which removes a negative, leaving a count of 2. You can count the others as well, since they will never become negative, resulting in A=0,B=0,C=0,D=1,O=1,E=1 when you add the C. Since the negative count is 0, you start removing characters from the start, which is A, dropping it to -1, and switching back to adding at the end.

You then add to the end until you reach an A again, which results in A=0,B=1,C=0,D=2,E=2,O=2 and a count of 0. Remove from the start until you reach a negative again, which removes D,O,B,E,C, since B's removal only drops it to 0, not a negative. At that point, the substring is "ODEBA" and C = -1. Add to the end until you reach a C and you have "ODEBANC", and remove from the start until you get a negative again, leaving "ANC". You've reached the end of the string and have a negative, so there is no shorter string remaining with all the characters.

You can retrieve the shortest substring by taking the start and end indices of the mapped substring whenever you switch from removing to adding and storing them if they are shorter than the previous shortest. If you never switch from removing to adding, then the result is the empty string.

If S="BANC" and T="ABC", then the result is adding until you reach "BANC", switching to remove, hitting a negative (and therefore copying those lengths at 0 and 3), and attempting to add beyond the end which ends the algorithm with the substring starting at 0 and ending at 3.

As every character gets adding once and removed once or less, it takes 2n steps at most to complete the algorithm, an O(n) solution.

[Idea from mike3](https://leetcode.com/discuss/5469/is-the-length-of-t-considered-constant-or-m)

Comment: smart answer! Two quick questions, (1) in your code, "[0] * 128" means? (2) what is the logical meaning/usage of ord?

Comment: updated my answer and find some issues in the implementation, appreciated if you could help to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A more 'pythonic' approach on the algorithm explained in http://articles.leetcode.com/2010/11/finding-minimum-window-in-s-which.html

*In short:* Use head and tail 'pointers', advance head until match is found, then advance tail (decrease the size of the window), while the substring still matches.

```
import collections

def windows(S, T):
    # empty string/multiset is matched everywhere
    if not T:
        yield(0, 0)
        return

    # target multiset initialized to contents of T
    target_ms = collections.Counter(T)

    # empty test multiset
    test_ms = collections.Counter()

    head = enumerate(S)
    tail = enumerate(S)

    # while the condition is not met, advance head 
    # and add to the test multiset
    # iterate over the whole input with head
    for i_head, char_head in head:
        test_ms[char_head] += 1

        # while the condition is met, advance tail
        # (and subtract from test multiset)
        # (a - b) for Counters has only elements from a that 
        # remained >0 after subtraction
        while not target_ms - test_ms:
            i_tail, char_tail = tail.next()
            yield (i_tail, i_head + 1)
            test_ms[char_tail] -= 1

def min_window(S, T):
    # initialize
    min_len = len(S) + 1
    min_start, min_end = None, None

    # go through all matching windows, pick the shortest
    for start, end in windows(S, T):
        if end - start < min_len:
            min_start, min_end = start, end
            min_len = end - start

    return (min_start, min_end)
```

Comment: nice code. :) Two quick questions, why you are using "yield(0, 0)" other than return directly? Another question is do not quite understand what this statement means "head = enumerate(S)"?

Comment: You need to go through some volume of python documentation before you understand the code.. google search for ```python enumerate``` will give you the [answer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) faster than me.

Comment: And for the `yield` - the whole function is a _generator_, a special kind of _coroutine_. Again, go through some examples that you can easily find on the web. `return` here means 'no more results', while `yield (0, 0)` means 'found a window starting and ending at index 0' - that's what the comment directly above is trying to explain.

Comment: followed your guidance to learn yield, want to confirm my understanding is correct, you call yield(0, 0) and return immediately after it, and it only handles situation of a corner case when T is empty (e.g. input is wrong)? Does yield(0,0) and return handles other cases in normal loop? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yep, it handles empty T. I decided that empty T matches everywhere, that is an empty substring (0,0) matches as well. Then there's nothing  to do, because you got the shortest possible match (0 characters), so I end the generator with return.

Comment: thanks and another confusion from your code is statement "target_ms - test_ms", wondering the logical meanings, and suppose there are elements in test_ms Counter but not in target_ms Counter, what is the behavior?

BTW, I have tested your code works for me. Super Cool!

Comment: You need to go 'out' and try it yourself. Run python interactively, create two `Counter`s with different contents and check what is the result of `a - b` and `b - a`. Did you try to read the comments in my code (stuff after `#` signs)?

Comment: I tested and I think a-b will output elements in a and not in b, want to confirm my understanding is correct since I do not find any document online about what means a-b. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

My C++ solution that runs in O(n) time (accepted solution at leetcode, runs faster than 99% of submitted C++ solutions):

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class CharCounter
{
private:
    const int fullCount;
    int currentCount;
    vector<pair<short, short>> charMap;

public:
    CharCounter(const string &str) :fullCount(str.size()), currentCount(0) {
        charMap = vector<pair<short, short>>(128, { 0,0 });
        for (const auto ch : str) {
            charMap[ch].second++;
        }
    };

    void reset() {
        for (auto &entry : charMap)
            entry.first = 0;

        currentCount = 0;
    }
    bool complete() const {
        return  (currentCount == fullCount);
    }

    void add(char ch) {
        if (charMap[ch].second > 0) {
            if (charMap[ch].first < charMap[ch].second)
                currentCount++;

            charMap[ch].first++;
        }
    }

    void subtract(char ch) {
        if (charMap[ch].second > 0) {
            if (charMap[ch].first <= charMap[ch].second)
                currentCount--;
            charMap[ch].first--;
        }
    }
};

class Solution
{
public:
    string minWindow(string s, string t) {
        if ((s.size() < 1) || (t.size() < 1))
            return "";

        CharCounter counter(t);
        pair<size_t, size_t> shortest = { 0, numeric_limits<size_t>::max() };
        size_t beg = 0, end = 0;
        while (end < s.size()) {
            while ((end < s.size()) && (!counter.complete())) {
                counter.add(s[end]);
                if (counter.complete())
                    break;
                end++;
            }
            while (beg < end) {
                counter.subtract(s[beg]);
                if (!counter.complete()) {
                    counter.add(s[beg]);
                    break;
                }
                beg++;
            }
            if (counter.complete()) {
                if ((end - beg) < shortest.second - shortest.first) {
                    shortest = { beg, end };
                    if (shortest.second - shortest.first + 1 == t.size())
                        break;
                }
                if (end >= s.size() - 1)
                    break;
                counter.subtract(s[beg++]);
                end++;
            }
        }
        return s.substr(shortest.first, shortest.second - shortest.first + 1);
    }
};
```

The idea is simple: iterate the source string (`s`) char by char using two "pointers", `beg` and `end`. Add every char encountered at the `end`. As soon as all chairs contained in `t` added, update the shortest interval. Increment left pointer `beg` and subtract the left char from counter. 
Example of usage:

```
int main()
{
    Solution fnder;
    string str = "figehaeci";
    string chars = "aei";
    string shortest = fnder.minWindow(str, chars);  // returns "aeci"
}
```

The only purpose of the `CharCounter` is to count encountered chars contained in `t`.